# Duplicate tags: [provisioning], [ios-provisioning] and [iphone-provisioning]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

These tags seem to be duplicates of each other, and should probably be merged.

- [provisioning](/questions/tagged/provisioning): 524 questions
- [iphone-provisioning](/questions/tagged/iphone-provisioning): 229 questions
- [ios-provisioning](/questions/tagged/ios-provisioning):56 questions

They all have minor wikis.

I propose that they all be merged into [provisioning](/questions/tagged/provisioning).

What do you think should happen here?

Comment: I added a synonym pointing [iphone-provisioning] to [ios-provisioning] and merged those two tags. As djechlin points out, [provisioning] is a little more generic and applies to more platforms than just iOS, so I'm leaving this separate for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iPhone and iOS should be merged under [ios-provisioning](/questions/tagged/ios-provisioning), since (to my information, I only learned of this just now) these refer to the exact same technical meaning of "provisioning" for iOS developers, and "iPhone" is inaccurate, as this process is device independent.

[provisioning](/questions/tagged/provisioning) should not be merged as that includes many, many questions under various topics, only some of which are related to iOS.

As for the question of whether the iOS ones should be merged under the general one, it seems to me no - it is referring to a specific technical process when developing and publishing for iOS, is it not?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII [tag:provisioning] is a way more general concept isn't it?  You can provision any resource in any technology setting  I'm assuming [tag:provisioning-profile] is actually ios-specific from your question.

Comment: Yes, and I've updated my question somewhat accordingly. I recognize that my tag wasnt exactly a dupe of the other ones, and removed it from the list.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII updated (rewrote) my answer.  Thoughts on the tail question?

Comment: I would say that it would be better to retag as both [tag:ios] and [tag:provisioning] together, instea of keeping that specific tag.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII if my assumption is correct, then I don't see the case for that.  It definitely means provisioning is just swallowing ios, so you would have to at least make a case that ios-provisioning doesn't deserve its own tag at all.  That sounds wrong.